# Find the Taylor polynomial for a function $f(x) = (1+x^2)^{1/3}$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

I have to find the Taylor polynomial $T_2(x)$for a function $f$ of grade $2$ around $x_0 = 0$ given by
$$
f(x) = (1+x^2)^{\frac{1}{3}} \ \text{for} \ x \in \mathbb{R}
$$
I am very new to Taylor polynomials so I think what I have done is correct but I am just unsure whether or not they should give something 'pretty'. I know that they are approximations so they probably shouldn't but are you able to tell me whether or not my calculations are correct as I need this to be correct to be able to do some other questions which relies on me having the Taylor polynomial correct.

I have done the following:

\begin{align*}
   T_2(x) & = \sum_{n=0}^2 \frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+\frac{f''(x_0)}{2!}(x-x_0)^2 \\
   & = f(0) + f'(0)(x-0) + \frac{f''(0)}{2!}(x-0)^2 = f(0) + f'(0)x + \frac{f''(0)}{2!}x^2
\end{align*}

Thus
$$
f(0) = (1+0^2)^{\frac{1}{3}} = 1^{\frac{1}{3}} = 1
$$
and
$$
f'(0) = \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{(1+0^2)^{\frac{2}{3}}} \cdot 0 = 0
$$
and lastly
\begin{align*}
  f''(x) & = (f'(x))' = \bigg( \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{\frac{2}{3}}} \cdot x \bigg)' = \frac{2}{3} \cdot \bigg(\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{\frac{2}{3}}} \cdot x \bigg)' \\
  & = \frac{2}{3} \cdot \Bigg( \bigg(\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{\frac{2}{3}}} \bigg)' \cdot x + \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{\frac{2}{3}}}  \cdot x' \Bigg) \\
  & = \frac{2}{3} \cdot \Bigg(   - \frac{1}{((1+x^2)^\frac{2}{3})^2} \cdot \frac{2}{3} \cdot (1+x^2)^{\frac{2}{3}-1} \cdot 2x  \cdot x +  \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{\frac{2}{3}}} \cdot 1  \Bigg)\\ 
  & = \frac{2}{3} \cdot \Bigg(  - \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^\frac{4}{3}}  \cdot \frac{4}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^\frac{1}{3}} \cdot x^2 +  \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{\frac{2}{3}}} \Bigg) \\
  & =  \frac{2}{3} \cdot \Bigg( - \frac{4x^2}{3(1+x^2)^\frac{5}{3}} + \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{\frac{2}{3}}} \Bigg) = \frac{2}{3} \cdot \Bigg (- \frac{4x^2}{3(1+x^2)^\frac{5}{3}} + \frac{3(1+x^2)}{3(1+x^2)^{\frac{5}{3}}} \Bigg) \\
  & = \frac{2}{3} \cdot \Bigg ( \frac{x^2+3}{3(1+x^2)^{\frac{5}{3}}} \Bigg) = \frac{2(x^2+3)}{9(1+x^2)^{\frac{5}{3}}}
\end{align*}

which if we evaluate in $x_0 = 0$ gives

$$
f''(0) = \frac{6}{9^{\frac{5}{3}}}
$$
Thus
$$
T_2(x) = 1 + \frac{6}{2! \cdot 9^{\frac{5}{3}}}\cdot x^2
$$

I know that this is a lot of calculations but I hope some of you still wants to help me.

Thank you very much.

Regards

Mathias

Comment: The induction on the number of derivatives will eventually lead you to this formula: [The binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series). So, maybe it would save you some time to learn it. $(1+x)^{1/3}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{1/3}{n}x^n$. Then you only need to compose with $x^2$ to get $(1+x^2)^{1/3}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{1/3}{n}x^{2n}$. Here $\binom{1/3}{n}=\frac{1/3(1/3-1)(1/3-2)...(1/3-n+1)}{n!}$.

Comment: Thanks so I should have used this to make the calculations easier and not so tedious?

Comment: There is a computational mistake in your derivative. It'd be easier to write $1/(1+x^2)^{2/3}$ as $(1+x^2)^{-2/3}$ and use the power rule (+ chain rule). There is also a simpler way, but I do not know if it is the spirit of the exercise: do you know the Taylor polynomial for $(1+x)^{\alpha}$? Then replace $x$ by $x^2$, and voila.

Comment: And you also made a couple of mistakes towards the end of simplifying. In the last line, the numerator must be $2(3-x^2)$, not $2(3+x^2)$. More importantly, after that you can't combine under the same exponent if it was **NOT** a common exponent: $A\cdot B^n\ne(AB)^n$.

Comment: $1+\frac{x^2}{3}-\frac{x^4}{9}+\frac{5 x^6}{81}-\frac{10 x^8}{243}+\frac{22
   x^{10}}{729}+O\left(x^{11}\right)$, first few terms from mathematica. You can verify with these for correctness.

Comment: Thanks everybody. I am probably supposed to use the Taylor polynomial for $(1+x)^a$ but I just tried to do this on my own before we have had the lecture.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest consists in using the standard binomial expansion at order $\mathbf 1$:
$$(1+u)^{1/3}=1+\tfrac 13u+o(u) $$
and substituting $u=x^2$, whence
$$\bigl(1+x^2\bigr)^{1/3}=\underbrace{1+\tfrac 13x^2}_{T_2(x)}+o\bigl(x^2\bigr).$$

Comment: How do you get $\frac{1}{3}x^2$? If $(1+x)^a = 1 + \alpha x + \frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)}{2!}x^2$ we have for $\alpha = 1/3$ that $(1+x)^a = 1 + 1/3 \cdot x + \frac{1/3(1/3-1)}{2} \cdot x^2$ Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Here,  $x^2$ takes the place of $x$ in the binomial, so we only need to expand to order  $1$, which will become an texpansion at order $2$ after substitution. If you initially expand at order $2$, you'll at the end obtain an expansion at order $4$.

Comment: Oh, ok. Makes sense. So it is correct to write the Taylor polynomial as $T_2(x) =(1+x)^\alpha = \sum_{n = 0}^1 \binom{\alpha}{n} x^n = 1 + \alpha \cdot x = 1 + \frac{1}{3} \cdot x^2$ when substituting $x = x^2$? And I am bit confused what the starting point $x_0 = 0$ matters in this context? At least when using this particular sum. Can you explain? Thanks in advance Bernard.

Comment: I don't see  what you mean with $x_0=0$? Is it a typo for $n=0$?

Comment: I am asked to find the Taylor polynomial $T_2(x)$ for $f$ of order $2$ around the point $x_0 = 0$. Does this just mean that the sum starts from $n = 0$?

Comment: No. We have a Taylor polynomial around any point $a$ of the domain (as far as the function is differentiable a sufficient number of times), but it is  a polynomial in $x-a$. Around $0$ (therefore with variable equal to $x$), it is known as the Maclaurin expansion.

Answer (score 0):

sorry your evaluation is wrong ist is NOT 9^(5/3) but just 9 so f''(0)=2/3
 you have much less work, wenn you set x=0 in your first equation. so you have not to evaluate the derivative in (...)'*x